# SalesforceDX: Log in to sandbox by username/password from command line without browser involved

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, jwt, salesforcedx-cli-auth

Is it possible to log in from sfdx CLI to already existent sandbox having username/password combination?

Reading through documentation I see bunch of ways how to authorize - through browser, by providing JWT token and consumer key, using existent access token etc. But cannot find a simple way how to do it in a browserless way just by providing username & password right in command line.

We just need to deploy code and run tests against our qa sandbox from CI pipeline - need to authorize an org somehow without human being involved. Is there a simpler way than following whole JWT authorization flow, i.e. creating connected app on each sandbox, upload certificate etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the auth command from the sfpowerkit plugin:

`sfpowerkit auth:login`

https://github.com/Accenture/sfpowerkit

It supports login with username-password combination (probably will need security token as well). A functionality that the standard CLI lacks

Answer (score 9):

`sfdx force:auth` only provides the JWT and web OAuth login methods:

```
sfdx force:auth commands: (get help with sfdx help force:auth:COMMAND)
 force:auth:jwt:grant      authorize an org using the JWT flow
 force:auth:logout         log out from authorized orgs
 force:auth:sfdxurl:store  authorize an org using an SFDX auth URL
 force:auth:web:login      authorize an org using the web login flow
```

But... there's a couple of different ways around the lack of a direct username/password login option.

One's to use `sfdx force:source:convert` to build a Metadata API package. Provided you have configured your sandbox so that CLI access doesn't require completing the verification code (or you're logging in with a security token), you can then use any existing Metadata API deployment tool (Force.com Migration Tool, Force.com CLI, etc) to perform the deploy using the username and password alone.

Another route is to login to the sandbox by hand *once*, locally, via `force:auth:web:login`. Then do `sfdx force:org:display -u <username> --verbose` to get the SFDX authentication URL, which starts with `force://` and includes the OAuth refresh token (not the session id). You can store that securely in an encrypted file and later load it into SFDX with `sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -f <thefile>`. (Credit to [CRMScience](http://www.crmscience.com/single-post/2018/01/22/Salesforce-Logins-for-Continuous-Integration-and-Delivery) for documenting this approach).

Comment: That's basically what we are doing now, i.e. using ant migration tool for deployment/test/apex execution and also selenium scripts to trigger some actions like package upload and installation. I was hopping to switch to sfdx CLI as a more reliable and consistent way of doing all that things. Suggested approach with auth url & refresh token doesn't look simpler than JWT + connected app, as for me. Probably would go ahead with JWT flow using the same certificate for all sandboxes to keep thinks simpler. Thanks.

Comment: I confirm the jwt approach + same certificate on all orgs , we use that and it works well :) Before calling the  jwt grant, I suggest to call force:org:list --json and parse the response to see if it is necessary

Comment: wish someone would write a plugin to do this..  It makes it a real pain when someone else references a sandbox and you can't get an confirmation code due to the email botching.  The only way to login is with the security token

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy can you that on sandboxes too via jwt?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 we use JWT login with developer and enterprise orgs , so I think that it should work too with sandboxes ( if you configured the related connected app ), but as we don't use sandboxes I have never experienced it myself