# Programatically add org authentication to SalesforceDX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, salesforcedx-cli-auth

I’m coding a sfdx plugin using the new plugin generator found here:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate

I was wondering if there’s a way to programatically add a new Salesforce org to the sfdx authenticated orgs.

Imagine invoking a `sfdx force:auth:...` command directly supplying username and password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SalesforceDX: Log in to sandbox by username/password from command line without browser involved](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227910/salesforcedx-log-in-to-sandbox-by-username-password-from-command-line-without-b)

Comment: @DavidReed possibly, but maybe not quite, since maybe via plugins there's a way to code the desired behaviour, however I still haven't found anything in the @salesforce/core repo that could lead to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JWT grant command, as explained here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm ( follow all the steps, and if you need to easily generate a certificate, you can use online sites like https://www.sslchecker.com/csr/self_signed for example )

You will need to locally store the Dev Hub org .crt and .key files , + eventually a JSON file containing your Dev Hub username and clientId

Then call force:auth:jwt:grant like in the example

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid YOURDEVHUBCONNECTEDAPPCLIENTID --jwtkeyfile /Path/to/devhub/certificate.key --username YOURSCRATCHORG@USERNAME.COM --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
```

We do that with a groovy script and it works perfectly fine, so i'm confident you can do the same using a SFDX plugin

Comment: Looks good, too bad it needs to previously create and authorize a connected app otherwise would be perfect for our use case. Since your answer indeed does solve my question I'll mark it as solved.