# ANT EOL / Migrating to SFDX. Can SFDX authenticate with just username/password+Token on the CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, authentication, ant

I've been using ANT for years.  I've written c# code that wraps around ANT so my users can put in the username, password & Token and hit go and it will call out to ANT, pull down what it needs (page layouts, translations, etc) adjust the XML as needed and then call out to ANT again to push it all back in.  It works great.
Now I've seen this: [Ant Migration Tool End of Life](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_deployment_ant_migration_tool_eol.htm&release=248&type=5).  It appears that Salesforce is going to stop supporting the use of ANT and they want us to use SFDX instead.  However, I can't seem to find a way with SFDX to just authenticate in without going through a whole "authorization" procedure first which doesn't work well since we are using this against an unlimited number (currently over 1800) of customer orgs.
Does anyone know of a way of converting this over to SFDX so it works the same?

ant RetrieveLayouts -Dsf.username="username@username.com" -Dsf.password="passwordandtoken" -Dsf.serverurl="login.salesforce.com" -Dsf.maxPoll=20

ANT has been great.  The build.xml allows me to do a lot including deleting and creating folders, logging, etc very easily.  I wish they wouldn't mess with that.  If I can't get SFDX to do it, I may have to go to fully coding everything directly to the API instead of just wrapping around something like ANT but I hate to have to do that if I don't have to.

Comment: SFDX authentication is far clearer and simpler, not requiring storing passwords in clear text. You use a separate command to authenticate a given org (and this is done automatically for new scratch orgs created using the CLI). As to the rest of your scripting, you can still use Ant. Just replace the tasks you used from the Salesforce tooling jar with executions of the CLI tool commands (`exec`) if you want to stick with Ant.

Comment: So how do I do SFDX authentication without popping up a login window in a browser and without editing anything in the org itself (can't create connected apps or install certs or anything like that in the org).  
I use SFDX/Visual Studio code without issue when working in my own developer org but when I have to touch hundreds of customer orgs it just is not "far clearer and simpler".

Comment: The SF CLI uses a standardized Connected App (you'll see its use on your developer orgs) and you *can* write code using whatever OAuth flow you want (and that the connected app permits) to authenticate against an org. However, a positive benefit of having the access and refresh tokens set up is that once you've logged in explicitly to an org you don't have to do so again. So my recommendation; update your tooling to actually allow the OAuth flow to open a browser window when required in order to receive the refresh and access tokens. Then your customers won't need to login again for that org.

Comment: I am not allowed to do so because it is our CUSTOMERS orgs that we are connecting to.  I am not able to create connected apps or setup any kind of OAuth flow.  Also, doing so in over 1800 orgs would be very painful.

Comment: You misunderstand me - you're not creating a Connected App. The SF CLI uses a standard one Salesforce created. It gets used against the org, not installed on the org. You don't have to set up anything on the org. Just allow the SF CLI to use the browser flow against the org using this standard Connected App, popping open the browser *when required* (and typically just the once for a given user/org/computer combo) to allow the user to authenticate. Honestly, this is not painful. You just need to update your tooling to work with it instead of against it.

Comment: I understand the browser flow.  However, it's confusing to my users to have to swap back and forth between the app and the browser.  And, I would force deauthenticate each org when done to ensure there is never a time that the wrong thing gets applied to the wrong customer environment so it would be every time, not just once per org.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SalesforceDX: Log in to sandbox by username/password from command line without browser involved](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227910/salesforcedx-log-in-to-sandbox-by-username-password-from-command-line-without-b)